# Hypernyms for "historic/archeological places", "churches/temples/mosques"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

We are building a travel app that will have categories of places like

1. Wild Life
2. Rivers
3. Beaches
4. Hill Stations

I also want to have categories describing the following:

1. Historic Places / Archeological Places
2. Churches/Temples/Mosques

What are the suitable single-word substitutions for these?

Comment: You might use "places of worship" for category 2. Category 1 is two distinct types of places. An archeological dig is often just a hole in the ground or a place like Olduvai Gorge, but historic(al) sites are usually buildings and battlefields and other places where important events occurred.

Comment: @BillFranke for Category 2 - can you suggest a single word.

Comment: Not a single word, but *religious sites* is only 2 words.

Comment: There are few nonsectarian possibilities: _tabernacles_ and _temples_ are the only two I can find.

Comment: For your first three items, [*Ecotourism Sites*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecotourism) might work, depending on how natural and undisturbed the places are. But Hill Station wouldn't fit there. If you're directing people to see the architecture of churches/temples/mosques, "Religious Buildings" might work; if you're sending them there for services, then "Houses of Worship" would be better.

Comment: "Hill Stations" is two words, not one, so why do you need a single word for the others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CED](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sanctuary) suggests that *holy places* such as temples and churches can be referred to as **sanctuaries**.

To describe *places of historical significance*, perhaps you can use the word **monuments**.

> **monument**
>
> an obelisk, statue, building, etc, erected in commemoration of a person or event or in celebration of something
>
> a notable building or site, esp one preserved as public property
>
> a tomb or tombstone

---

A little suggestion for your app that you may find useful:

you can create a special section called **the UNESCO World Heritage Sites**
where you can have places that are listed by the [**UNESCO** (United Nations Educational, Scientific and Cultural Organization)](http://whc.unesco.org/) as of special cultural or physical significance.

Here is a link to the [list](http://whc.unesco.org/en/list).

Comment: Both the words seem to be apt....but I think *Sanctuaries* is a bit uncommon usage in this context, so users may not understand its use  just by its name.

Comment: @Mohit Yeah.. That's why I suggested _holy places_ too :) But _holy places_ may sound weird to the users.

Comment: Terry Pratchett had a Council of Churches, Temples, Sacred Groves and Big Ominous Rocks...